# DxlImporter inside a loop throws error " DXL importer operation failed"

Tags: import, xpages, document, javaagents, ibm-doors

I am having a java agent which loops through the view and gets the attachment from each document, The attachment is nothing but the .dxl file containing the document xml data. I am extracting the file at some temp directory and trying import the extracted .dxl as soon as it get extracted.

But the problem here is ,it only imports or works on first document's attachment in the loop and throws the error in java debug console

```
NotesException: DXL importer operation failed
at lotus.domino.local.DxlImporter.importDxl(Unknown Source)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My java Agent code is

```
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
static DxlImporter importer = null;

public void NotesMain() {

  try {
      Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();



      // (Your code goes here) 
      // Get current database
      Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();

      View v = db.getView("DXLProcessing_mails");
      DocumentCollection dxl_tranfered_mail = v.getAllDocumentsByKey("dxl_tranfered_mail"); 
      Document dxlDoc = dxl_tranfered_mail.getFirstDocument();
      while(dxlDoc!=null){

          RichTextItem rt = (RichTextItem) dxlDoc.getFirstItem("body");

          Vector allObjects= rt.getEmbeddedObjects();

          System.out.println("File name is "+ allObjects.get(0));
          EmbeddedObject eo = dxlDoc.getAttachment(allObjects.get(0).toString()); 
          if(eo.getFileSize()>0){
         eo.extractFile(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + eo.getName()); 

          System.out.println("Extracted File to "+System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + eo.getName());
           String filePath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + eo.getName();
           Stream stream = session.createStream();
          if (stream.open(filePath) & (stream.getBytes() >0)) {
            System.out.println("In If"+System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

             importer = session.createDxlImporter();
           importer.setDocumentImportOption(DxlImporter.DXLIMPORTOPTION_CREATE);
                  System.out.println("Break Point");

        importer.importDxl(stream,db);
        System.out.println("Imported Sucessfully");
      }else{
          System.out.println("In else"+stream.getBytes());


      }

      }
            dxlDoc = dxl_tranfered_mail.getNextDocument();   

   }
   } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The code executes till it prints "Break Point" and throws the error but the attachment get imported for first time

In other case if i hard code the filePath for the specific dxl file from file system it imports the dxl as document in the database with no errors

I am wondering if it is the issue of the stream passed doesn't get completes and the next loop executes.

Any kind of suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Short answer: move the individual operation in its own method and limit the loop to calling the method, recycle and advance to the next doc. And recycle!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any part where your while loop would move on from the first document.

Usually you would have something like:

```
Document nextDoc = dxl_tranfered_mail.getNextDocument(dxlDoc);
dxlDoc.recycle();
dxlDoc = nextDoc;
```

Near the end of the loop to advance it to the next document. As your code currently stands it looks like it would never advance, and always be on the first document.

If you do not know about the need to 'recycle' domino objects I suggest you have a search for some blog posts articles that explain the need to do so.
It is a little complicated but basically, the Java Objects are just a 'wrapper' for the the objects in the C API.
Whenever you create a Domino Object (such as a Document, View, DocumentCollection etc.) a memory handle is allocated in the underlying 'C' layer. This needs to be released (or recycled) and it will eventually do so when the session is recycled, however when your are processing in a loop it is much more important to recycle as you can easily exhaust the available memory handles and cause a crash.

Also it's possible you may need to close (and recycle) each Stream after you a finished importing each file

Lastly, double check that the extracted file that is causing an exception is definitely a valid DXL file, it could simply be that some of the attachments are not valid DXL and will always throw an exception.
you could put a try/catch within the loop to handle that scenario (and report the problem files), which will allow the agent to continue without halting

Comment: Hi thanx for the reply , but as i can see it was typing mistake from me.but I am not performing dxlDoc.recycle();

Comment: I have tried doing this solution but the exeption throws at "        importer.importDxl(stream,db);
"

Comment: a few things, are you absolutely sure the extracted file is valid dxl? Does it still work first time and fail on the second time? does closing the stream after each import make any difference? how about putting a try catch inside the loop, so if it fails on one document it will still move on to the next. are you 100% sure the dxl is always the first embedded object? why not loop through the vector instead? also as a side note you definitely should be recycling embedded objects when finished with them as otherwise they won't clean up temporary files that they secretly created.

Comment: You are right, Its the problem of dxl data. the thing to take care of importing the dxl data should be perfectly exported.

Comment: great to hear it is working! is it ok if you could accept my answer as the solution so the question is not left as 'unanswered'

Comment: dxl data coming in a stream was the issue which i have explored and verified that it  have empty line at the start of the file so that the importer throws an error, your comment was right.

Comment: ok I've updated the answer to include the comment about valid DXL. ok to accept the answer now?

Comment: Yes actually dxl import/export is actually a very goot alternative to transfer data from one database to other. :)